# Direct iphone towards a star - geolocation flip

Tags: actionscript-3, geolocation, accelerometer, heading

With AS3 I combined geolocation and accelerometer to direct the iphone, with its back towards a star at the sky. Accelerometer works fine for tilt 0-90 degrees ( directed towards horizon, phone vertical - towards zenith, phone horizontal with screen downwards) but geolocation heading of course flips around 45 degrees tilt and begins to show star direction + 180 degrees. Around 45 degrees tilt geolocation heading becomes very random and I would be very grateful for a suggested algorithm to eliminate the randomness of this phase shift.